Is there a better way of building this <T> object?
For the method below, is there a better way of building the returned object?
It's of type <T>.
The first input parameter has the same type as the returned object.
The last builder parameter is what makes me anxious.
It currently points to a static factory method in each T class.
If you wanted to avoid passing the builder param, how would you handle that?
(I would prefer not to resort to a cast, and to use a technique that is friendly towards immutable objects.)
public <T extends FourVector> T transformVector(T input, TransformInto direction, Function<Map<Axis, Double>, T> builder) {
  //the core calculation uses matrices, so we convert back and forth like so
  Matrix input_matrix = Matrix.asMatrix(input);
  Matrix result = physicsMatrix(direction.sign()).times(input_matrix);
  //I need to build a new T object here; hence the builder param
  return builder.apply(asComponents(result));
}


You wrote a function named Λ? Why? Maybe give FourVector an asMatrix() method. And rename Λ.

Λ and your Builder are both extremely difficult to type.

Lambda corresponds to physics formulas for the Lorentz Transformation. That's all.

Your solution looks optimal.  There is not, in general, a better way of building generic types.

It is possible to do this with some reflection and unchecked casts. Would you prefer that over your current approach? I wouldn't.

I have changed the unusual method name.

I experimented with about 6 different variations.
The best I could come up with involves creating an explicit Builder interface for building the desired object.
The basic idea is that the incoming input object is of the correct type T already, so it makes sense to ask that object to build a new object of the same type T.
private <T extends FourVector & Builder<T>> T transformVector(T input, TransformInto direction) {
    //the core calculation uses matrices, so we convert back and forth like so
    Matrix input_matrix = Matrix.asMatrix(input);
    Matrix output_matrix = lambdaMatrix(direction.sign()).times(input_matrix);
    return input.build(fromComponents(output_matrix));
  }

With the Builder interface as the translator from the lower-level data structure to the desired higher-level data structure:
public interface Builder<T> {
  
  /** Build a new T object out of the given components. */
  public T build(Map<Axis, Double> components);

}

The unusual thing about this is that object creation is not through a constructor, but through a regular object method.
